# Rolling Mean from fixed starting point (and by Group)

Tags: r, function, moving-average

Suppose you have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(100)
Pts <- floor(runif(20, 0, 10))
Individual <- c(rep("Adam",5), rep("Ben",5), rep("Charlie",5), rep("Daisy",5))
Date <- c(rep(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-05"), "days"), 4))
RollMean <- rep(NA,20)

df <- data.frame(Pts, Individual, Date, RollMean)
```

I would like to to calculate what the mean RollMean for Pts is for each row, by Individual, but only including entries between the earliest date and the date on the current row.

For example:

```
df$RollMean[3] = (5+2+3)/3
df$RollMean[4] = (5+2+3+0)/4
df$RollMean[7] = (8+4)/2
```

I have tried using functions such as `SMA()` from the `TTR` package and then using `ave` to sort by Group, such as:

```
df$RollMean <- ave(df$Pts, df$Individual, FUN= function(x) SMA(x, n))
```

but there I have to pre-specify `n` which changes based on which row R is dealing with.

What code can I use to generate the Rolling Means I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,cumsum(Pts[order(Date)])/seq(.N), Individual]
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works great. If I wanted to use some of the more complicated moving average functions in TTR such as EMA() and WMA(), is there a way of incorporating these without manually imitating/breaking down these calculations?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few alternatives:

**1)** This does not use any packages:

```
transform(df, Rollmean = ave(Pts, Individual, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)))
```

**2)** An alternative is to use zoo's `rollmeanr` with vector of widths:

```
library(zoo)
Rollmean <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x), mean))
transform(df, Rollmean = ave(Pts, Individual, FUN = Rollmean)
```